# Would I receive a confirmation email when I turn off iCloud backup?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, email

Will I receive a confirmation email (to Gmail, the email I registered my device) in case I turn off the iCloud backup function on my device?

Comment: What has your research show so far? Have you tried it?

Comment: @Tetsujin This isn't something that can be tested trivially, since it would require you to actually disable your iCloud backup to test.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not receive an email.